# Apache server configuration for virtual domains

Tags: apache2

I have created a website and hosted it on apache.

I add users to my website and what i want is that each user gets his/her subdomain as userA.mysite.com, userB.mysite.com and so on. I know that blogspot.com works like this but i am not able to get proper configuration.

I had used wilcard domain configuration but upon the second page again redirects to the main domain. e.g. i logged in using userA.mysite.com but after login i am redirected to my profile on mysite.com

Can someone guide on what configurations i make to get this work?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why in the world is this tagged JavaScript?

Comment: Sounds like there is some sort of software installed as your website. Which one? A redirect to the basic domain is not done by Apache with the default settings. It is most likely that this redirect is performed by the software installed.